# value error while trying to join a channel using telethon

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I have a code that I need to join a given channel in but getting the following error

> telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.ChannelInvalidError: Invalid channel object. Make sure to pass the right types, for instance making sure that the request is designed for channels or otherwise look for a different one more suited (caused by JoinChannelRequest)

my code :

```
group_input = InputChannel(group.id, group.access_hash)
client(JoinChannelRequest(group_input))
```

here I'm using inputChannel because i looked in the joinChannelRequest and it asked for "TypeInputChannel"
and it's a union of [InputChannelEmpty,InputChannel,InputChannelFromMessage]

another things that I tried:

1-

```
client(JoinChannelRequest(group.id))
```

2-

```
client(JoinChannelRequest(group))
```

3-

```
group_input = InputPeerChannel(group.id, group.access_hash)
client(JoinChannelRequest(group_input))
```

Comment: do you have the link or the username for the channel you want to join ?

Comment: yes,I have the link

Comment: but in some cases I wouldn't have either the link or the user name and I need to handle that too , I may have id

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way you can do is to retrieve the username of the public channel
Suppose the username of the channel is `@The_Channel`
Get the entity
`entity = client.get_entity("t.me/The_Channel") #omit @`
Then invoke this function
`client(JoinChannelRequest(entity))`